# AUv3 AudioUnit Extension, IPCAUClient: bundle display name is nil

Tags: audiounit, auv3

In my AUv3 AudioUnit Extension I get this error message on the debug console output:

```
IPCAUClient.cpp:129:ConnectToRegistrationServer: IPCAUClient: bundle display name is nil
```

But there is a name in the info.plist file ... does anyone has the same problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This literally took me WEEKS to find the details to get this to work proper. There is NO sample code from Apple that would explain how this is supposed to work.

The main problem was to get the remote viewcontroller from the plug-in on the first start of the containing app. The AUv3 plug-in works perfect when it was inserted in Garageband once that would handle the registration to the system, but without this step there was no remote ViewController available.

I saw other implementations that read the AUv3 viewController from the bundle and connect the UI elements to the headless controller - this is boilerplate code and poor style IMO ... better use an `AVAudioUnit` and derive the `AUAudioUnit_XH`  including the `AUAudioUnitRemoteViewController` from there by using this wrapper:

`AU_AudioUnit = AVaudioUnit.AUAudioUnit`

To get the AudioUnit to work inside the containing app there are several dependencies:

1. The AUv3 plug-in need to be registered using the `registerSubclass` method.
2. There needs to be an observer on `AVAudioUnitComponentManagerRegistrationsChangedNotification` installed.
3. The `Inter-App Audio` feature needs to be switched on in entitlements!

I hope this helps you out there and saves you lots of long and lonely nights ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, very surprised to find some info on this, the docs are just non existent. Could you please explain how you got the audio unit's VC to display in Garageband? I am able to get the audio unit displaying in the lists of both GarageBand and AUv3Host but no view controller.

Comment: Okay, I just did some digging around and got it working. This post really helped, thanks!